# Does anyone know how to build an error free FluffyChat android apk?

Tags: android, flutter, client

I'm trying to build the FluffyChat client as an android application, but when I try I get errors like: "Execution failed for task ':flutter_olm:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'." and "FAILED: libolm.so"

Source Code: https://gitlab.com/famedly/fluffychat/-/tree/main

There is a tutorial on READ ME to build, even following it gives these errors.

[image: 1]

I tried installing libolm3 library, still to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried to build the android version of FluffyChat recently, and managed with a few minor updates:

For the libolm3 issue itself, I managed to avoid it by using the flutter installation from the tarball (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux) instead of the snap version: see https://gitlab.com/famedly/fluffychat/-/issues/1065

Then, I update the webrtc repository in pubsec.yaml file:

```
   flutter_webrtc:
-    git: https://github.com/radzio-it/flutter-webrtc.git
+    git: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc.git
```

Finally, the build command currently tries to sign an apk, so you'd need a keystore and a file referencing it (maybe you could find a way to build a debug version of the apk without this signature?.
I just created an android/key.properties file with the content:

```
storePassword=xxx
keyPassword=xxxx
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/path/to/your/storefile
```

then I built running the commands:

```
git apply scripts/enable-android-google-services.patch
./scripts/build-android-apk.sh
```

Comment: note that the automated build have several warnings/errors logged, even when successful: https://gitlab.com/famedly/fluffychat/-/jobs/3807150262

Comment: Just in case somebody like me comes here I had to delete old flutter entirely using sudo snap remove flutter